# additional attributes are collected in one colomn,separated only with comma, i want split into separate columns into multiple columns

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, importexport, additional-options

in magenro 2 All additional attributes are collected in one colomn, separated only with comma. Here is also "cost" placedi want to [image] Extend the standard Entity Type 'Products', so 'additional_attributes' is split into separate columns. Magento standard exports the additional attributes into one column and separates them by using a comma inside the column. We want it to be split into multiple columns.